# Why does my computer get messed up when using gnome-screenshot? (Linux)

Tags: linux, gnome, screenshot

When using gnome-screenshot to capture a particular area of the screen, my computer gets messed up for around 30 seconds.

By "messed up" I mean:

- The screenshot tool does not immediately display the capture I just took. It takes about 30 seconds or so for the completed capture Window (the one that has the "copy to clipboard" button and a preview of the captured screenshot) to show up.
- Various inputs don't seem to work. For example, when I click on input boxes in Chrome, the input boxes won't receive focus. Clicking on particular parts of certain applications also don't work. After the screenshot Window displays, everything is back to normal.

It feels like gnome-screenshot is locking some resource and getting stuck, but only for about 30 seconds (sometimes less, sometimes more).

How can I go about diagnosing this and solving this problem?

Comment: In Gnome, in Ubuntu 20.04, in Screenshot, did you set a Delay?   That might be the reason.

Comment: No, I don't have a delay set. The delay feature being turned on also wouldn't explain why mouse input is getting messed up.